# About Time conditionals

Tags: date, timestamp

I'm trying to compare times like:

if this post was posted between the past 6months show `human_time_diff()` else show      `the_time('j. M .Y')`

my idea was:

```
function time_ago() {
  global $post;
  $now = time();
  $post_created = strtotime($post->post_date);
  $sixMonthsAgo = 180*24*60*60;
  $human_time = 'hace '. human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') );
  $mobile = wp_is_mobile();


  if (( $now - $post_created ) > $sixMonthsAgo && $mobile) {
   the_time('j. M .Y');

 } elseif(( $now - $post_created ) > $sixMonthsAgo && !$mobile) {
   the_time('j. F .Y');

 } else {
   echo $human_time;

 }

}
```

What I pretend to do with this function is comparing the date when the post was published and because `time()` is in seconds I compare seconds with seconds in `$sixMonthsAgo`

But this only shows the `human_time_diff();`

no more ideas ...

what do you think ? where my logic is wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it works for me with minor changes:

```
  global $post;
  $post_created = strtotime($post->post_date);
  $sixMonthsAgo = strtotime('-6 months');
  $human_time = 'hace '. human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') );
  $mobile = wp_is_mobile();

  if ($post_created > $sixMonthsAgo && $mobile) {
   the_time('j. M .Y');

 } elseif( $post_created > $sixMonthsAgo && !$mobile) {
   the_time('j. F .Y');

 } else {
   echo $human_time;

 }
```

I hope this simplification helps :)